# Syntax Error (Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried running the code:

```
var DETAIL_IMAGE_SELECTOR '[data-image-role="target"]';
var DETAIL_TITLE_SELECTOR '[data-image-role="title"]';
var THUMBNAIL_LINK_SELECTOR '[data-image-role="trigger"]';
```

running it through JSHint and it says:

```
15  Missing semicolon.
15  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
16  Missing semicolon.
16  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
17  Missing semicolon.
17  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
```

There's a semicolon after all the statements..... what gives?

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign the values to the variables:

(ie. use the `=` sign)

```
var DETAIL_IMAGE_SELECTOR = '[data-image-role="target"]';

var DETAIL_TITLE_SELECTOR = '[data-image-role="title"]';

var THUMBNAIL_LINK_SELECTOR = '[data-image-role="trigger"]';
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign a value to a variable you must use the equal sign ('=').

For example :

```
var a = 'hello world!';
```

Also, you should consider using 'let' and 'const' instead of 'var'. Finally, although it's not a mistake, you should generally use camelCase in JS.